# Why do I get "Incompatible types when assigning" error?

Tags: c

I'm having C code which seems to have similar pointer assignments but shows different behaviours while compiling .

My structure declaration and definition is below,

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    char b[20];
}
TestStruct;
TestStruct t1;
```

Why does the below code gives "error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[20]’ from type ‘char *’"

```
t1.b = "Hello World";
```

but the code below compiles successfully,

```
char *charPtr = t1.b;
charPtr = "Hello World";
```

Note: I'm using GCC compiler v4.6.3

Comment: A pointer is like someone's name; what it points to is like the  person with that name. Imagine trying to stick a person into the line on a form that asks for a name, or putting the name of a person on a chair instead of the person hsrself ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ths strings cannot be assigned to arrays in C, unless as part of an initialization.
The right way to do something like that is by means of the function `strcpy()` of ths `<string.h>` standard header.

```
    strcpy(t1.b, "Hello world");
```

It is not true that the array `t1.b` is a pointer to char.
Actually, it has type **array of 20 elements of type char**.
In an expression, the array normally decays to a **pointer to char**.

However, the array has a fixed address in memory. It is not an lvalue, its address cannot be changed by an assignment.

The opposite assignment is valid:

```
  charPtr = "Hello World";
```

The address of the string "Hello world" is assigned to `charPtr`.
However, your sentences have not the intended effect:

```
   char *charPtr = t1.b;
   charPtr = "Hello World";
```

The effect is that `charPtr` becomes equal to the address of `t1.b`.
Then, this value is discarded in the second sentence and replaced by the address of the array "Hello world".

**More details:** Be carefull in handling strings. A string literal like "Hello world" is an array stored (in general) in only-read memory. If you try to modify it, you can obtain unexpected results.

In particular, this happens with the assignment charPtr = "Hello world".
The string can be read, but not changed.

To change or manipulate a string, it has to be **copied** (with `strcpy()`) to an array or to an allocated portion of memory.

Comment: And when you say "A string literal like "Hello world" is an array stored (in general) in only-read memory"...Does this memory usage counts to the total memory allocated and does this memory gets overwritten without our knowledge?

Comment: While the program is running, the string will be there, without any changes. Don't worry about that. However, if you try to access that portion of memory and attempt to modify their bytes, very probably will occur an error. Something likd `"Hello"[3] = 'x'` could bring execution errors or well extrange and subtle behaviour. This dependes on the compiler or the environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly assign a string literal to a `char` array.  Use `strcpy()` or `strlcpy()`.

In the second example, the array decays into a pointer, and then you change that pointer. Note that in this example, `t1.b` remains unchanged.

Comment: But I was thinking 't1.b' and 'charPtr' are pointers which are pointing to same location . But both the assignments have different results. Please correct me If i'm wrong

Comment: @user3665376: There are two misconceptions there. Firstly, arrays and pointers are not the same thing: http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html. Secondly, even if you have two pointers and change one, this does not change the other.

Answer (score 0):

When you define:

> typedef struct {
>      int a;
>     char b[20];
>   }TestStruct;

b is a **constant pointer** pointing to char. Hence t1.b = "Hello World"; is a compiling error since it change the value of t1.b

Solutions:

1) Use strcpy:

```
    strcpy(t1.b, "Hello World");
```

2) Tricky type-casting way

```
    char** pb = (char**)&t1.b;
    *pb = "Hello World";
```

Although these 2 methods bring the same purpose (setting t1.b to "Hello World" string), the underlying idea is very different.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot assign `const char*` to `char[]` as it violates constancy.